# Layer 4 Load balancing - TCP Handshake

Tags: load-balancing

I am newbie to load balancing concepts.

This is regarding a Layer 4  Load Balancer. I would like to know if the packets intercepted at IP layer by the Load Balancer would read the TCP header information and then route the traffic to the destination server or if the load balancer would have a TCP Handshake with the Client and  act as a reverse proxy for the request. Basically I would like to know if the TCP Handshake happens with the destination server or with the Load Balancer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no one answer to this, it depends on what hardware/software you're using and how you choose to configure it. If you have a specific answerable question then please ask it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's actually a Layer 4 LB, then no, Sessions (TCP) are handled at Layer 5. Anything below that would have to pass the packet through for the server to establish the session.

That said, it might be stretching the definition of a Layer 4 LB. Are you looking at specific hardware or software?